# Save parts of an ontology into different files

Tags: ontology, protege

The [Pizza Ontology tutorial](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A3Y8T6nIfXQ_UQOpCAr_HFSCwpTqELeP/view) demonstrates the development of Ontologies using [Protege](https://protege.stanford.edu/) and the complete Ontology is saved into a [single file](https://github.com/owlcs/pizza-ontology/blob/master/pizza.owl).

Is there a way to split a complete ontology, such that each class and each Object property are saved into separate files?